# How do I create a background image that is also resized on aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a loading screen for my GMOD server and the background image has to be resized(cropped) if they are playing on a 4:3 monitor. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Resized and cropped are two very different things. Do you mean shrunken to fit the screen or the same size with the edges chopped off?

Comment: I assume you don't want the photo to get distorted when the aspect ratio is different?

Comment: same size with the edges chopped off

Comment: and yes i dont want it to be distorted

Answer (score 1):

You could use bootstrap's responsive image class. You could specify an aspect ratio and the image will adjust responsivly.

Comment: where would I find this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img{   
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="your_img">
</body>
</html>
```

however there will be white space on the bottom. You can just do:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img{   
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="your_img">
</body>
</html>
```

But that will distort the img. There is no way to make the img fit perfectly with changing screen size without white space and/or distorion.

Comment: Great! this works! how would I place css3 round corner boxes ON TOP of the image? or does it have to be a background?

Comment: Well, you could set the img to have a position of absolute and then you could add the boxes like normal, style them/place them like normal and use border-radius: 22px; for the curved edges